# What does drelu[z ​<= ​0​] ​= ​0 mean?

Tags: python, artificial-intelligence

I am currently reading the nnfs book by Harrison Kinsley, and in describing the derivative of the ReLU function in back propagation, he uses this code

```
drelu ​= ​dvalues.copy()
drelu[z ​<= ​0​] ​= ​0
```

Where he is essentially replacing all the values of drelu with zero where the corresponding element in z is less than or equal to 0. What does the second line mean/do, what is the particular thing happening (just asking so that I can understand what is going on and to use it for future projects).

Python btw

I got an np array that was equivalent to the z array but every value that was <=0 was 0 (expected output)

Comment: That looks like numpy magic to me.  It's not standard Python.

Answer (score 5):

`z <= 0` creates a boolean array of the exact same size as `z` that is True in those locations were `z <= 0` and False elsewhere.

`drelu[a_boolean_array] = 0`  sets `drelu` to 0 only at those locations where the boolean array is True. If the two arrays are different sizes, various broadcasting happens, but that's not an issue here.

Combining these two, you can see that `drelu[z <= 0] = 0` sets `drelu` to 0 at the locations where `z` is less than or equal to 0;

Answer (score 0):

I was not super familiar with how `numpy` (presumably) was set up so I went about trying to make my own data type with the same behavior. I think it might be illustrative as an example to help understand *how* a library might be set up to support this syntax:

```py
class Thing:
    def __init__(self, inner):
        self.inner = inner

    def __le__(self, val):
        return Thing(list(map(lambda x: x <= val, self.inner)))

    def __setitem__(self, key, value):
        if isinstance(key, Thing):
            for i, v in enumerate(key.inner):
                if v:
                    self.inner[i] = value
        else:
            self.inner[key] = value
    def __repr__(self):
        return str(self.inner)

z = Thing([1,2,3,4,5])
print(z <= 3)
d = Thing([1,1,1,1,1])

d[z <= 3] = 0
print(d)
```

Running this small script we can see that `print(z <= 3)` will convert the base `Thing` into an `Thing` containing boolean values by calling our custom `__le__` method on `Thing`. When we pass that to the index syntax and the custom `__setitem__` method is now called.

At the end of the day, it seems the library is taking extreme advantage of pythons data model to provide more convenient short hands for some common operations. The downside is that the uninitiated may find this behavior unexpected and difficult to read / reason about.

To fully understand the range of options `numpy` allows, you have to turn to their docs: https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/arrays.ndarray.html#indexing-arrays